# Can GetFile/ListFile/FetchFile Be Configured To Repeat List For Each Trigger?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to be able to list all files in a directory every time the flow is triggered. I am running into the following problem

a) With ListFile + FetchFile - All files in folder are listed once, but it remembers state, so that next time it runs it does not list any file unless the file has been modified. I would like the ListFile + FetchFile to run exactly as before. I can go and manually delete 'state' info. But this not configurable

b) With GetFile approach and with KeepSource=true, the processor repeated keeps listing the files again and again. It would like it to happen only once.

Is there a way this can be configured to repeatedly list files whether it has changed or not and only once?

Comment: What do you mean by repeatedly listing files only once?

Comment: Just change the scheduling of GetFile to run once a day?

Comment: @mattyb I would like the files to be listed only once and not repeatedly

Comment: That's what ListFile does, lists them only once. What are you trying to do differently than that?

Comment: @mattyb - The problem with ListFile is that it lists only once. Running it again, will not result in the list again as it stores the state. GetFile always gets files in a folder but it does so repeatedly. I need a way to be able to list files in a folder every time a flow is triggered and the files need to be listed just once.

Comment: What do you mean by "triggering the flow"? Do you start then stop the source processor (ListFile or GetFile)? If so then Bryan's comment is good, just schedule GetFile to run once in a long time, then trigger the flow by starting and stopping GetFile. It will not have time to get scheduled again, so it will only run once per "trigger".

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first question to ask is why do you want to list everything repeatedly?

NiFi is a tool for building flows, it is meant to process new data as it comes in, not so much processing all data over and over again. It seems very likely that you are in one of these scenarios:

1. By redesigning the flow you should not need to list everything repeatedly
2. You are doing something which should not really be done with NiFi.

There are many tools which can list files and are happy to do this again. (A simple shell command, or even some python or spark code).

a. If you are looking for an orchestrator: Consider something like Oozie or Airflow

b. If you really need you can let Nifi execute a script instead of using ListFile, but as mentioned it is very likely that you are going in a direction where you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for the party, but dropping in just incase it gets useful for someone else.

You can use the `ListFile` processor property to achieve it using the `Listing Strategy` setting it to `No Tracking` allows the processor to list all the files each time the processor is triggered.

[image: ListFile property]